# can i use variable outside function when i select by onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `job`";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

<select class="form-control " id="jobposition" onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)">
    <?php 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0){
      while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
                                                  ?>
  <option value=<?php echo $row3["jobid"];?> ><?php echo $row3["position"]; ?></option>
   <?php }} ?>
 </select>

 <script>                                                   
  var job ;
   function getSelectValue(jobid) {                        
   this.job = jobid;
 }
```

I want to use selector outside the function.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You could return it from the function and therefore call the function any time you need it if that helps. A more detailed use case would help

Comment: I edit code already. can you help me, please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access the variable outside the function. The  variable just needs to be defined globally, i.e. outside the functions.

```js
var selector = document.getElementById("jobposition");
var disp = document.getElementById("optSelected");

function getSelectValue() {
  disp.innerHTML = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control " id="jobposition" onchange="getSelectValue()">
  <option value="none">Select position</option>
  <option value="1">Position 1</option>
  <option value="2">Position 2</option>
  <option value="3">Position 3</option>
  <option value="4">Position 4</option>
</select>

<div>Selected option is = <span id="optSelected"></span></div>
```

Comment: yes, but i want to use selector real time and then it change value when i select option. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. The demo shows the HTML being updated with the value of the selected option every time the option is changed.

Comment: yes yes,i understand but i don't want to show that, 
I want to keep the value  to global Variable outside function and value will change when i select option .